# Why there's a bijection between a set and its subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have in my notes the following: Let $A,B$ be two non empty sets, we know that $B\subseteq A$, therefore there's a bijective function between them.

Why there's a bijective function between them ?

Comment: This is true and only if $B$ is infinite.

Comment: For every set $B$ there is a set $A$ for which the statement doesn't hold; for instance $A = B \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Comment: @GitGud I think you meant $A$. alright, why is it true if the sets are infinite and why not when they're finite ?

Comment: I meant $B$. It's not necessarily true if $B$ is infinite,look at the comment above. How are you defining finite/infinite set?

Comment: @user133281 can you explain why it's false for this set ?

Comment: @GinKin It's an easy consequence of [Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem).

Comment: @GitGud this is from memory, if the set is uncountable then it's infinite, also if it's cardinality is $\aleph_0$ then it's infinite.

Comment: @GinKin To elaborate, $B$ can be of any cardinality; $A = B \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ will be of greater cardinality, so the bijection can't exist.

Comment: @GinKin The assertion in your comment above is true.

Comment: To do your question justice, we would need more context. Of course, if you've figured out what the notes mean with the help of the comments so far, then that's good, but if not, we don't really have much information to go on as it is.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein it had to do with two sets, one was all binary sequences and the other all natural numbers sequences. Both have the same cardinality so that's why it worked there, I just wanted to know if it's true for all sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to compile the discussion in the comments into a short answer.

In general, the result is false because $A$ might be of a different [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) than $B$. (Or, more simply, they might both be finite and of different orders. Let $B = \{1\}, A = \{1,2\}$.)

In the particular case where $B$ and $A$ are both infinite and have the same cardinality (example: $B$ is the natural numbers and $A$ is the integers) then this is true. In fact, infinite sets can be defined as being those sets which are in bijection with at least one of their proper subsets. Note that no finite set has this property; all of the examples look like our counterexample in the second paragraph.